# Laravel route parameters don't care at all

Tags: laravel, parameters, binding, routes

I come from here:
[Laravel pagination trouble with offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126058/laravel-pagination-trouble-with-offset)

Investigating into my code, I found that when a random **alike** parameter is given through a route, it will do an **like** query or I don't know, but it will still work as it will get the first part of the parameter:

[image]

The route I'm trying to "ensure" goes like this:

```
Route::get('/videos/cats/{race_id}/{cat_id}, [App\Http\Controllers\MeowController::class, 'getCatVideo']);
```

Can someone help me to get **that** exact parameter as integer, or prevent a route from working if the parameter is not exactly the given one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something like [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are required by default.

To validate parameter:

```php
Route::get('/videos/cats/{race_id}/{cat_id}, [App\Http\Controllers\MeowController::class, 'getCatVideo'])
    ->where('race_id', '\d+')
    ->where('cat_id', '\d+');
```

Useful link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked by specifying the parameter as [0-9]+

Comment: BTW, is it possible to do the same with Laravel Pagination?

Comment: @DavidEncinaMartínez You can validate query params using validation in FormRequest: 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

P.S.: Mark the answer as solution if it helps.